# Will the 3 day Stream trade waiting period happen for every trade?

Tags: steam

My question is if I don't use the Steam mobile authentication from the Steam app  **will I have to wait 3 days each trade I make or will this happen only a set amount of times**? (Would much prefer they had the 2FA done by SMS or something that doesn't relies on the app, because of the nuisance it creates each time I log into Steam)

This is because I have Steam trading cards I want to trade, and I want to know if this wait time will apply each time I trade with someone.

Comment: I think so, but if you are friends with someone for +1 year (I think dunno?) It will only take a day...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will happen every time you make a trade now. This was part of the recent changes made to the trading system, and is detailed further [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8078-TPHC-6195):

> If a user trading away items hasn't had their account protected by a Mobile Authenticator for the past 7 days or has turned off trade confirmations, item delivery will be delayed by Steam for up to 3 days (1 day if you've been friends for at least a year.) This provides the user time to cancel the trade and any other that are pending.

The only way to get around this is to have an account protected by a mobile authenticator, with trade notifications turned on.

Comment: Thanks, for the info @Jeeva. To bad that it is the way it is.